# How to loop through all pixels of an image in a windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-8

I'm actually trying to loop through all pixels of an image in a windows phone 8 application.
Basically, in a Class Library I use this kind of "unsafe code".

```
unsafe {
    byte* prSrc = (byte*)(void*)d;
    byte* prDest = (byte*)(void*)s;

    for(int y = 0; y < bitmap.height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++)
        {
            // do some work here
        }
    }
}
```

But in Windows Phone 8 it is not possible. Do you have a workaround or something like that ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows Phone, images can be manipulated via the `WriteableBitmap` class.

The `WriteableBitmap` class has a `Pixels` property that is an array containing every pixel of the image in ARGB32 format (premultiplied RGB).

The simplest way to loop and read/write on every pixel is to use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) (open source library that you can install via NuGet).

Then you can use the `ForEach` extension method, like this:

```
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(myImage, null); 
writeableBmp.ForEach((x, y, color) => 
{
   // Read and write on the color object
   return color;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the msdn sample for the WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer)